# How shall we treat Magmi related questions?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Off-topic or not? With some arguments please.

Comment: Good question, I have not dealt with it from a development point of view before so I was treating it like another 3rd party module. Is it different in some way?

Comment: Technically it is a 3rd party tool. Same as modman or composer. So while being independent it has quite tight connection with Magento.

Comment: Is there good support offered somewhere for it?

Comment: No, at least is was not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is my approach on questions related to third party modules, not just Magmi. Let me know if it's right or not.

I don't vote to close a question related to third party modules right away. There is a chance that someone else has used that extension and fixed the problem in the question.
So I let the question live for some time.
If the question does not get any answer it is usually bumped up by [Community](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community). When I see it bumped up I vote to close.

I think we should treat Magmi questions the same.

Comment: That is a very nice approach

Comment: Agree also but only regarding free modules.

Comment: @Tim. I forgot to mention that. For paid modules I vote to close them right away, notifying the OP to contact the developer.

Comment: I think this is a very legitimate approach.

Comment: @Marius, Why people ask questions about paid modules here and not at the developer's site?

Comment: @Amasty. What do you mean? This question is about how should modules related questions be handled.

Comment: @Marius, sorry for being unclear. "how should modules related questions be handled" question can be solved by answering the question "why people post them here?" So, for example, 1) if we add a hint (as current hints) before posting answer to NOT ask questions about paid modules because it's advertizing, we can just close such questions.  2) At the other hand, if people do not get proper support from the extension developers and really need help for paid module customization/fix we can allow both questions and answers IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

**Should Close**

1. Not core module or custom module made by user asking the question,
2. I don't know anything about it so I cannot get the point ;)

**Should Keep Open**

1. If they add something to the website,
2. If there are lots of people asking questions then there is a need for these questions,
3. If there are people on the site/we can get on the site that can provide answers, there is no point having questions open for a while with no hope of an answer, it is not good for the site in terms of users respect for the site or plain and simply the stats :)

Comment: Is there a way we could flag those questions as "off-topic because... 3rd party module related question" ? Because the only options that are given by "off-topic" are not relevant to the situation

Comment: @JulienLachal you can add a custom message that you can use. I think we did get an extra close option before so maybe it would be a good idea to get another one.

Comment: yes but, it would involve less reading for the mods if there was a special option for that specific kind of "off-topic" questions. I don't know if we can ask for this in here.