# Abusive post editing?

Tags: support, editing

Hi fellow Magento addicts.

So, from time to time, on the main question feed page, there seem to be a big load of questions (with accepted answers or not) that come back from the grave. After looking at the edition history, it looks like those questions were just edited to either add a tag, or just correct small typos.

So my question is, what's the point? Is it just to gain some reputation (which would be really lame)? is it you think you have to do the [Community](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)'s job? is it you think it's important to add new tags to old posts? or is it you think it's important to bring up old unanswered questions so as the OP's acceptance rate rises? (but what about the answered questions being bumped then?)

I'm just curious that's all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are talking about me.
I'm certainly not doing it for the reputation.
I don't get any rep from editing posts anymore.
I just wanted to clean up this website a bit.
I've been doing this for a while (not just editing, but answering, voting, closing, re-tagging).

My reasons? See this: [The quality of MageOverflow](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/317/146).

I'm looking through old questions, try to bump the ones without accepted answers, maybe someone can view them. There are a lot more members now than they were 9 or 12 months ago, maybe some of the new guys have an idea on old questions.
Also I'm trying to properly tag questions so they can be found easily by new-comers. A lot of them have only a single tag that state the magento version, or they are wrongly tagged.

Other have poorly formatted code, that hurts my eyes.
Others have signatures in the question or answer, that ..well...see this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5038/224252

I'm sorry that this is received as abusive.
I will take your question as a first "thumbs down". If other users complain about this I promise to stop.

> No good deed goes unpunished.

**[EDIT]**

And I don't know if you noticed, but I edit new posts also.

Comment: Imma buy you a broom when I come see you in Cluj.

Comment: @benmarks. You're coming to Cluj, just to see me? aww...that's nice.

Comment: I wasn't specifically refering to you, and I acknowledge you're doing a really good job in here, don't get me wrong, but I was just wondering the reasons behind this, thank you.

Comment: and I wasn't asserting it as being abusive, hence the question mark :p

Answer (score 4):

adding new Tags can be a big help for others, who only use tags to finde Questions to answer.

In My Example, I mainly observe questions with the Tags Composer and phpunit, if the questions dont have the tag, I will not find them, so its a good thing to have some people wo regularly go trough older questions and add this tags, so other more specialized people can find and answer them.